# Render template in Flask by keeping changes made with Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm creating a web app with Flask, and to get the input from the user I'm using a from with text input. There is the possibility for the user to add more textboxes in the form, for that I used Javascript:

```
function addRow(myTable, elemType){
  var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
  var totalRowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(totalRowCount-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  var n1 =(totalRowCount-1).toString();

  cell1.innerHTML = (totalRowCount-1).toString()+': ';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input  type="text" name="'+elemType+'x'+ n1 +'">';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input  type="text" name="'+elemType+'y'+ n1 +'">';
}
```

The problem is that when the user submits the form, the page is reloaded (with the flask *render_template* function) and the changes made with javascript are lost.

How can I keep these modifications made to the html? Is there some command like *return render_template('new_index.html', variables = myVariables)* where *new_index* is the html file modified by JS?

Thank you in advance